# how can i divide two columns in SQL using java?

Tags: java, mysql

[ https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCdLW.png]i am a beginner in java.....i made a button using GUI to get two columns from a table in SQL, then i want to divide them and put the result in the same table in a new column,i succeeded to make the connection and make the new column, and i found a code that helped me to get the two columns and make the operation on them and put it back in the same table but when i opened the SQL i found the column but it contains just "NULL" .....and when i run my code it gives me no errors and there is my button:

private class Handler_c implements ActionListener{

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/database_vf","root","");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);

            Statement stmt1 = null;
            stmt1= conn.createStatement();
            String sql1 = "Alter table Rssi Add result double";
            stmt1.executeUpdate(sql1);
            PreparedStatement pst1 = null;
            //Row row;
            //Statement stmt11 = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            double i,j;
            double array=0;
            ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT a3, a4 FROM rssi");
            while (rs.next()) {

                i= rs.getInt("a3");
                j= rs.getInt("a4");
                if(j==0){array=0;}
                else{array=((i/(j/10))-112);}

            }

             String query3="INSERT INTO rssi (result) VALUE ('"+array+"')";
             pst1 = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query3);
             pst1.execute();


            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("Success insert result to mysql table");
        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Run the query `SELECT * FROM rssi WHERE a3 IS NULL;` and tell us what you find.

Comment: sorry but where i can put this?

Comment: In your `mysql` client, or phpMyAdmin console, or whatever you use to administer the db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that your error is in the line

String query3="INSERT INTO rssi (result) VALUE ('"+array+"')";

you have to put **VALUES** not value

String query3="INSERT INTO rssi (result) **VALUES** ('"+array+"')";

**EDIT**

I got it:

First of all you are replacing all the time the *i* and *j* value with the last value that appears and after the last value you go to the database (and I suppose that's not the idea)... to avoid that you have to put

```
String query3="INSERT INTO rssi (result) VALUE ('"+array+"')";
pst1 = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query3);
pst1.execute();
```

into the While block...

Secondly... you are creating new records... if you check the data in the table... the last records will have null in all the columns except in result...
You have to UPDATE each record, not INSERT new ones.

Try your code like this:

```
int recordId;
double i,j;
double array=0;
ResultSet rs = stmt1.executeQuery("SELECT primaryKey, a3, a4 FROM rssi");
while (rs.next()) {
    recordId = rs.getInt("primaryKey");
    i= rs.getInt("a3");
    j= rs.getInt("a4");
    if(j==0){
        array=0;
    }else{
        array=((i/(j/10))-112);
    }
    String query3="UPDATE rssi set result ="+array+" WHERE primaryKey = "+recordId;
    pst1 = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query3);
    pst1.execute();

}

conn.commit();
conn.close();
System.out.println("Success insert result to mysql table");
```

Obviously in "SELECT primaryKey, a3, a4 FROM rssi" change **primaryKey** for your primary key column's name.

Comment: mmm... the result column in your database is double type... so is not necesary put '' in the values... try 

String query3="INSERT INTO rssi (result) VALUES ("+array+")"; (without the ')

Comment: Run the query as  Darwin von Corax says or put a screenshoot of the data in the table and show to us that

Comment: I will thank you if check the answer like correct ;)

Comment: I mean mark the answer as correct... In order that "close" the question and get the points for the right answer ;)